# SASS @each duplicating selector with placeholder

Tags: css, sass

I am having some problems with the SASS `@extend`

I have the following code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AgCnF?editors=110

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

### SASS

```
$link-different: 1, 2

li
    @if $link-different != 0
        %different-background
            background: #000

        @each $different in $link-different
            &:nth-child(#{$different})
                @extend %different-background !optional
    @else
```

But it is outputting two `li` elements on the CSS selector path

### CSS output

```
li li:nth-child(1), li li:nth-child(2) {
  background: black;
}
```

### Desired CSS output

**How can I make it output this?**

```
li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2) {
  background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code on [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/)

```
$link-different: 1, 2

%different-background
  background: #000


li

  @if $link-different != 0

    @each $different in $link-different

      &:nth-child(#{$different}) 
        @extend %different-background !optional

  @else
```

---

Output

```
li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2) {
  background: black; 
}
```